# JPEG: Any dimensional size limits?

Tags: jpeg

Specifically, 220400w x 5400h.  Any problems (besides of course machine limitations) to generating images of this dimension?

Comment: Have you heard of google?
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=maximum+size+of+jpeg
First result http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG
"It supports a maximum image size of 65535×65535"

Comment: Googles?  Like you wear when swimming? You must be new here, otherwise you would recall Joel's idea that SO would be the first result for any search query regarding programming.  At least you didn't include l m g t f y.com in your now-deleted answer.

Comment: And now it comes full circle, pointing to here: http://bit.ly/W43qys The universe is complete.

Comment: (I hope I won't get in trouble for this, but it was just too beautiful an occasion to pass)

Comment: Mpelletier, sweet... Truly a thing of beauty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max dimensions of a JPEG file are 64K x 64K.